# use the same dataTableOutput in different tabs

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a possibility to reuse a `dataTableOutput` in several tabs? The only possibility I found was using a layout where the `dataTableOutput` gets its own row but I don't want it above all tabs.

If I just call the `dataTableOutput` multiple times, none of the tables get printed.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer of daattali I got this almost done. The only thing I didn't mentioned before was, I need the two tables synchronised in a way. At the moment, when I try to update each other via proxy, the whole system gets buggy when selecting to many rows in a short time...

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509041/add-hovereffects-e-g-tooltip-to-one-large-plotly-table#51551597

Comment: Did you find out how to synchronise the two tables? It would help me greatly. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you solved it in the end... I used in the end only one table and had my app spread on several tabs... https://butterlab.imb-mainz.de/flydev/?data=embryogenesis

Comment: Cool job there! My table is too wide, si I'd like to thin it out with a tooltip resource

Comment: That is also a good idea, will keep it in mind for the next project

Answer (score 6):

You can't use the same id (since you can't have two elements on the same page with the same id), but what you can do is generate the table once as a reactive value and then simply return that value inside the render table functions. This has the benefit of only running the code for generating the table once, and re-using the table in as many outputs as you want.

Example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tab1", "tab 1", DT::dataTableOutput("table1")),
    tabPanel("tab2", "tab 2", DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table_data <- reactive({
    DT::datatable(iris)
  })
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(table_data())
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(table_data())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ok, this sounds good. And I guess I have to use a proxy to synchronise the selected rows between the dataTables, or is there an easier way?